# Stopping messagebox from looping the entire textfile after it found a value

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, messagebox

i created register and login app. I made a messagebox that pops up when it found a value in the textfiles and also when it doesnt find the value. However it keeps looping my entire textfiles so it loops untill it find the value. How do i prevent it form looping? I tried break but it made it stop at 1st row of textfiles. Please ignore the register button, just the login function at the moment.

[the textfiles(users) for login info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB3mf.jpg)

```
from tkinter import *

import time

import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox



##3 

#### Variable

##3



window = Tk()

window.geometry("600x400")

window.title("Bookloaner")

stud = open("users.txt","r")

logdin = False

username = "admin"

password = "admin123"

stud = open("users.txt","r")

books=[]

books = open("books.txt","r")



##3

#### Define

##3



def closer():

    frame.pack_forget()

    logframe.pack_forget()

    regframe.pack_forget()

    extframe.pack_forget()

    time.sleep(0.1)

####2

# FRAMES

####2





logframe=Frame(window)

regframe=Frame(window)

extframe=Frame(window)



def Login():

    closer()

    def Chek():
        
        for line in open("users.txt", "r").readlines():
            loginn_info= line.split()

            if name.get() == loginn_info[1] and passwd.get() == loginn_info[2]:
                tkMessageBox.askokcancel("System","logged",)
                
            else:
                tkMessageBox.askokcancel("System","Error",)
                

    frame.pack_forget()

    conf = StringVar()

    mesg=Entry(logframe, width=30,textvariable=conf,fg="#900",state="readonly",relief=FLAT)

    mesg.grid(row=0,column=2)

    labname=Label(logframe,text="What is your name?")

    labname.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)

    name=StringVar()
    entname=Entry(logframe, textvariable=name)

    entname.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

    labpass=Label(logframe,text="What is your password?")

    labpass.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

    passwd=StringVar()
    entpass=Entry(logframe, textvariable=passwd)

    entpass.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

    checkbtn = Button(logframe, text="Login", fg="#fff", bg="#00f", command=Chek)

    checkbtn.grid(row=3,column=2, sticky=E)

    logframe.pack()





def Register():

    def Chek():

        for i in stud.readlines():

            i.rstrip("\n")

            i = i.split(":")

            print(i)

            if username in i[0]:

                if password in i[1]:

                    print("logged in!")

                    break

                else: print("wrong username or password")

            else: print("User doesn't exist.")

    frame.pack_forget()

    logframe=Frame(window)

    labname=Label(logframe,text="What is your name?")

    labname.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)

    entname=Entry(logframe)

    entname.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

    labpass=Label(logframe,text="What is your password?")

    labpass.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

    entpass=Entry(logframe)

    entpass.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

    checkbtn = Button(logframe, text="Register", fg="#fff", bg="#090", command=Chek)

    checkbtn.grid(row=3,column=2, sticky=E)

    logframe.pack()







def Exit():

    window.quit()

    exit()







def Getbook():

    closer()

    def Chek():

        firstnaem = firstnaem.rstrip("\n")

        lastnaem = books.readline().rstrip("\n")

        books += [[firstnaem,lastnaem]]

        for i in books.readline():

            print(i[0])

            

    extframe = Frame(window, height=400, width=600)



    bname=StringVar()

    leftframe=LabelFrame(extframe, height=400, width=300)

    Label(leftframe, text="Get",font="25").place(y=0,x=0)

    Label(leftframe, text="Book ID").place(y=30,x=10)

    nr=Entry(leftframe, width=45).place(y=50,x=10)

    Label(leftframe, text="Book Name").place(y=70,x=10)

    Entry(leftframe, textvariable=bname, width=45,state="readonly",).place(y=90,x=10)

    Button(leftframe, text="Get", width=38, height=10, bg="yellow", command=Chek).place(y=121,x=9)







    leftframe.place(y=0,x=1)



    rightframe=LabelFrame(extframe, height=400, width=300)

    Label(rightframe, text="Give",font="25").place(y=0,x=0)

    

    rightframe.place(y=0,x=300)

    extframe.place(y=0,x=0)







##3

#### Start

##3



frame = Frame(window, height=400, width=600)

welcom=Label(frame,text="Welcome to Book Extange v1",font="50")

welcom.grid(row=0,column=2)

button1 = Button(frame,text="Login",font="25",width="10",height="3",bg="#00f",fg="white",command=Login)

button1.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=W)

button2 = Button(frame,text="Register",font="25",width="10",height="3",bg="#090",fg="white",command=Register)

button2.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=E)

frame.pack()







closebtn = Button(window, text="Close", bg="red", command=Exit)

closebtn.place(x=560)



##3

#### DROP DOWN

##3



menubar = Menu(window)

navmenu= Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

navmenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=Exit)

navmenu.add_command(label="Home")

navmenu.add_command(label="Login", command=Login)

navmenu.add_command(label="Register", command=Register)

navmenu.add_separator()

menubar.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=navmenu)

navmenu.add_command(label="Extange",command=Getbook)





window.config(menu=menubar)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `break` after the line `tkMessageBox.askokcancel("System","logged",)`.  Also the `else` block should be in same indentation of the `for` line.

Below is the modified `Chek()`:

```py
    def Chek():
        for line in open("users.txt", "r").readlines():
            loginn_info = line.split()
            if name.get() == loginn_info[1] and passwd.get() == loginn_info[2]:
                tkMessageBox.askokcancel("System", "logged")
                break  # break out the loop    
        else:
            # credential not found
            tkMessageBox.askokcancel("System", "Error")
```

Comment: Thank you! i thought else supposed to be after if hence if else, guess i was totally wrong